# Bing Map Route Optimization

Tags: c#, javascript, bing-maps

I have 3 waypoints and a start point, i need to find out the nearest point(out of 3) from my start point, My question is does Bing provides any APIs which picks up the nearest waypoint from the startpoint, like resolving Travelling salesmen problem.

I went through the following links,
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh699893(v=VS.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh699893%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) - cross browser issue

http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Route%20Optimization%20-%20RouteSavvy%20Module - Commercial

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Kirankumar

Comment: Are you trying to solve the Traveling Salesperson problem (best route from start, through all 3 points, back to start) or, just find the nearest first point from a starting point?

Comment: Hi Matt, i am trying Travelling Salesperson problem

Answer (score 2):

Bing Maps does not provide traveling salesmen type route optimization, however it is possible to do this. The route optimization in Bing Maps provides the shortest route for a set of points of the order they are provided in. What you can do is generate a distance matrix using a single multi-waypoint route from start - p1 - start- p2 - start - p3 and so on. You can then use the distances to generate your optimized order of points. Take a look at this code sample:  http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Bing-Maps-trip-optimizer-c4e037f7

Comment: Thanks Ricky, i will try to bring in your approach.

Comment: Update: Another option is the Azure Maps routing service which provides travelling salesmen routing natively for up to 150 waypoints: https://azure.com/maps